# How to find rows with the sequence of values in a column using SQL?

Tags: sql

Consider the example table name "Person".

```
Name    |Date   |Work_Hours
---------------------------
John|   22/1/13     |0
John|   23/1/13     |0
Joseph| 22/1/13     |1
Joseph| 23/1/13     |1
Johnny| 22/1/13     |0
Johnny| 23/1/13     |0
Jim|    22/1/13     |1
Jim|    23/1/13     |0
```

In the above table, I have to find rows with the sequence of '0' followed by '1' in the column Work_Hours. Please share the idea/Query to do it.

The output I need is

```
Name    |Date   |Work_Hours
---------------------------
John|   23/1/13     |0
Joseph| 22/1/13     |1
Johnny| 23/1/13     |0
Jim|    22/1/13     |1
```

Comment: Must the rows be ordered by date?

Comment: @carexcer it sems he used `group by name,date`

Comment: You are looking for the second John line, because its value is zero and the next line (the first Joseph line) has a value of 1? And for the second Johnny line because of the first Jim line? What is the sort order? I don't see any.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It should be sorted by Name, then date

Comment: Okay. It isn't sorted by name in your example. At least not alphabetically.

Comment: data in SQL doesn't have an inherent order. Order must be specified by an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To look into previous or following records, you would usually use the aggregate functions LAG and LEAD:

```
select first_name, work_date, work_hours
from
(
  select first_name, work_date, work_hours
    , lag(work_hours) over (order by first_name, work_date) as prev_work_hours
    , lead(work_hours) over (order by first_name, work_date) as next_work_hours
  from person
)
where (work_hours = 0 and next_work_hours = 1) or (work_hours = 1 and prev_work_hours = 0)
order by first_name, work_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like

```
select no_hours.Name, no_hours.Date, some_hours.Date
From Person no_hours
inner join Person some_hours 
On no_hours.Name = some_hours.name and some_hours.Date > no_hours.date
Where no_hours.work_hours = 0 and some_hours.work_hours = 1
```

would be a start.

Needless to say, name is not a good unique identifier...

Also works hours going from 0 to 1 to 0 would appear, and 0 to 1 to 0 to 1 would appear a lot...

Would be >= no_hours.date if you can go from 0 to 1 on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT p1.Name, 
       p1.Date AS Date_1, 
       p2.Date AS Date_2, 
       p1.Work_Hours As Work_Hours_1,
       p2.Work_Hours As Work_Hours_2
FROM Person p1
INNER JOIN Person p2
  on p1.Name=p2.Name 
  AND p1.Work_Hours=0
  AND p2.Work_Hours=1
ORDER BY p1.Name,p1.Date,p2.Date,Work_Hours_1,Work_Hours_2
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a957b/3/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (as phrased) is equivalent to asking:  Is there a `1` that follows any given row with a 0 for a `name`?

You can do this  a correlated subquery:

```
select Name, Date, Work_Hours
from (select t.*,
             (select min(date)
              from table t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.date > t.date and t2.Work_Hours = 1
             ) as DateOfLater1
      from table t
     ) t
where DateOfLater1 is not null and work_hours = 0 or
      (DateOfLater1 = date and work_hours = 1);
```

Comment: Your problem re-write is not correct. The question asks "... to find rows with the sequence of 0 followed by 1" you are changing this to "... find rows with the sequence of 0 _or_ 1 followed by 1"

Comment: @Tony . . . I accept that.  But I still can't figure out from the question whether the row with the `1` should be included.